# jQuery submit function not working after an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have some code like this:-

```
$('#log').click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        if($email.val().length>=4 && $email.val().length<=64 && $password.val().length>=4 && $password.val().length<=64){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/login/check',
                data: {email: $email.val(), password: $password.val()},
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    if (data.email==0) {
                        $em.css('display', 'block');
                        $em.html('Email does not exists.');
                    } else if(data.verify==0){
                        $pass.css('display', 'block');
                        $pass.html('Password is incorrect');
                    } else if(data.email==1 && data.password==1 && data.verify==1){
                        $em.html('');
                        $em.css('display', 'none');
                        $pass.html('');
                        $pass.css('display', 'none');
                        $('#form').submit();  //form to be submitted
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('There is an error try again later');
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
```

Here $em and $pass are message box for messages and #log is submit button. When user clicks on button with id log some ajax calls are called and if everything is 1 (i.e. data.email, data.password, data.verify) the form is to be submitted using jQuery's submit function but it does not happens.
What is going wrong here. And what can be the solution for it?

Comment: can you share the form html as well? are you appending or replacing any html anywhere?

Comment: share your form

Comment: Is the log button also the submit button for the form?  Is there any other validation on the form / form submit?  Can you reproduce the issue on a completely empty page `<html></html>` just by adding your form, inputs, button and the above js?

Comment: Log button is inside form